# Contravariance in generics java doesnt work as expected

Tags: java, generics, contravariance

```
   List<? super Number> myNumsContra = new ArrayList<Number>();
    myNumsContra.add(2.0F);
    myNumsContra.add(2);
    myNumsContra.add(2L);

    System.out.println(myNumsContra.get(0)); //should throw error
```

According to the contravariance rule for generics the get(0) call above should throw a compile error. But I don't see this happening. Is there something I missed ? I am using Java-8

Comment: see the javadocs for the method you are using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)

Comment: Why should `get(0)` exactly throw an error?

Comment: Was reading this article (https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance) that says if the List class had put a bound such as, ? super T, then I wouldn't be able to call get(0) as the compiler would throw an error.

Comment: I dont see why this needs to be down voted - I asked a valid doubt. isn't that what stack overflow is for ?

Comment: The downvoters thought that you are asking why you don't get an error on calling `get` itself (presumably because of the index parameter type), rather than about what you do with the result. Your question is phrased a bit misleading.

Comment: My understanding is wrong the question is as you said

Answer (score 4):

There is no compile-time error, because `println` can take any `Object` (which is what even a `?` is guaranteed to be compatible with).

The error you are looking for is

```
Number x = myNumsContra.get(0);
// does not compile, because we cannot know this is really a `Number`.
```

Comment: Thanks I missed that :) so it really means it  cant assign to a type!

Comment: Not without a type-cast, no.

Comment: @jtkSource: "so it really means it cant assign to a type" Other than `Object`